# Doing long upload and then executing some network request while app is in background?

Tags: ios, background-service

There are not a ton of tutorials about background session for long upload requests. Here is my question, can I configure my NSURLSession to support background execution:

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "com.myCompany.backgroundUpload")
let session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
```

I start upload and app goes to background. Then after upload finishes, I want to trigger some API request. Typical scenario I uploaded large file to some service like Amazon / Dropbox and then I want to let my server know where the file is stored.